# Условие программы: удалить все нули в одномерном массиве (тема: массивы и указатели)

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, память

На массив нужно динамически выделить и перевыделить память, к элементам массива нужно обращаться через указатели. Проблема с реаллоком - работает коряво. Помогите разобраться, как мне уменьшить (или увеличить, например, если по условию нужно будет добавлять элементы) размер массива в моём цикле, заранее спасибо.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "time.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main() 
{
    int i, j, n, c = 0, * a, *A, k = 0; 
    printf("N: "); 
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    srand(time(NULL));
    a = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    if (!a) return -1;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", *(a + i) = rand() % 9 - 6); 
    printf("\n");
    for (i = j = 0; i + j < n; i++) 
    { 
        while (c == *(a + i + j))
        {
            j++; 
            *(a + i) = *(a + i + j);
            k++;
        }
    }
    i -= *(a + n - 1) == c;
    A = (int*)realloc(a, (n-k) * sizeof(int));
    if (!A) return -1;
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        printf("%d ", *(a + j));
    }
    free(A);
    return 0;
}
```

Примеры:

```
1 пример:
1)входные данные:   2 1 -6 -5 2 2 0 -1 -1 -2; 
2)итоговые данные:  2 1 -6 -5 2 2 -1 -1 -1;
3)ожидаемые данные: 2 1 -6 -5 2 2 -1 -1 -2;

2 пример:
1)входные данные:   -1 0 0 -5 -3 -2 -5 -1; 
2)итоговые данные:  -1 -5 0 -5 -3 -2;
3)ожидаемые данные: -1 -5 -3 -2 -5 -1;
```

Comment: "_работает коряво_" в чем конкретно ошибка/проблема?

Comment: вот 2 примера из консоли после запуска:
1 пример (N=10):
(2 1 -6 -5 2 2 0 -1 -1 -2); -    
(2 1 -6 -5 2 2 -1 -1 -1).
2 пример (N=8):
(-1 0 0 -5 -3 -2 -5 -1); -
(-1 -5 0 -5 -3 -2)

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос (нажав на кнопку "Править" ниже вопроса) 1) Пример входных данных 2) Пример выходных данных вашей программы 3) Выходные данные которые вы ожидали увидеть

Comment: Написать *(a + i + j) вместо a[i + j] не означает использовать указатели. Препод такой идиотизм врятли оценит.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков как раз это и значит использовать указатели. Операция называется "разыменование **указателя**"

Comment: @ПавелЕриков неа, обращение то все равно идёт по индексу. На одном почившем сайте об этом писалось, но другой ещё более древний сайт ещё жив http://www.c-cpp.ru/books/ukazateli-i-massivy

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков не соглашусь! Есть оператор индексации `[]` а есть `*`. `a + i` - арифметика **указателей**, `*(a + i)` - разыменования **указателя**. Не вижу разницы особой между `int* a = arr; ++a;` и `arr + 1`. Можно вместо `*(arr + i)` написать `int* a = arr; a += i; *a` Это я к тому, что это одинаковые подходы. Максимум не до конца раскрыта тема указателей, но все же указатели. Вы скинули сайт "_Указатели и массивы_". Где написано  "_арифметические действия с указателями ... чем индексация массива_" зачем сайт разделил указатели и индексацию, если это одно и то же?

Comment: @ПавелЕриков "Это я к тому, что это одинаковые подходы." - естественно, ведь это серавно доступ по индексу. А вот на сайте в примере используются 2 различных подхода.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков господи, вы такой ... В общем вы или меня тролите, или не до конца разбираетесь в теме, в любом случае не хочу продолжать этот разговор. Я все расписал, а вы лишь выхватили предложение и очень мягко говоря, написали бред.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще всего выкинуть из массива нули -- это тупо переписать массив сам в себя, пропуская нули.

Если хочется сделать это с указателями (а не индексами массива), то вот возможный фрагмент кода

```
  int *end = a + n;  // `a` -- это исходный масив из `n` элементов, выделенный по `malloc()`
  int *to = a;

  for (int *f = a; f < end; f++)  // вот и весь цикл, выбрасывающий нули
    if (*f)
      *to++ = *f;

  printf("now %d elements\n", n = to - a);
  a = (int *)realloc(a, n * sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 2):

Предложу ещё модифицированный вариант программы, с некоторыми комментариями. На мой взгляд, он более понятный и тут лучше раскрыта тема работы с указателями:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "time.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main() 
{
    int i, n, k;
    int c = 0;
    int *a, *A, *a_end, *p, *p_next; 

    printf("Enter n: "); 
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    a = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    if (!a) return -1;
    a_end = a+n;    //указатель за конец масива

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (p = a; p < a_end; ++p)
        printf("%d ", *p = rand()%9-6); 
    printf("\n");

    //ищем первый ноль
    for (p = a; p<a_end; ++p) 
        if (*p==c) break;

    //удаляем нули
    p_next = p;
    while ((++p_next)<a_end)
    {
        if (*p_next==c) continue;
        *(p++) = *p_next;
    }

    k = p-a; //новый размер масива

    if (k)
    {
        A = (int*)realloc(a, k*sizeof(int));
        if (!A)
        {
            free(a);  //функция realloc() сама не освобождает память при неудаче
            return -1;
        }
        a_end = A+k;

        for (p = A; p<a_end; ++p)
            printf("%d ", *p);
        printf("\n");

        free(A);
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Empty array!\n");
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Как вы представляете себе раелизацию `realloc()`, которая завершается **fail при уменьшении** массива?

Comment: @avp  void* realloc(void* data, int sz)
 {
  void* new_d = malloc(sz);
  if (new_d)
  {
   memcpy(new_d, data, min(prev_sz, sz));
   free(data);
  }
  return new_d;
 }

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков, это вы так пишете?

Comment: @avp неа. Но реаллок который может сфэйлится на уменьшении я представляю именно так. И это далеко не худший вариант из тех, что я встречал.

Comment: @avp эм... а что вы предлагаете? Писать код, основанный на внутренних деталях реализации библиотечных функций? Вы когда код пишите, проверяете как реализована каждая используемая вами библиотечная функция что ли?

Comment: @avp я и не должен себе представлять реализацию библиотечной функции. В описании к ней чётко не написано, что она не может возвратить NULL при уменьшении размера массива, а значит корректнее будет эту потенциальную возможность учитывать в коде, тем более что много ресурсов такая проверка не отнимает.

Answer (score 1):

Объясню на примере в чем ошибка вашего кода:

```
1 0 -4 3
```

На моменте когда вы доходите до `0` вы заменяете его на `-4` и увеличиваете `k` до 1.

Получаете вот такую картину:

```
1 -4 -4 3
```

И перевыделяете память удаляя последний элемент. Получаете вот это:

```
1 -4 -4
```

Вот пример кода с комментариями:

```
//2 итератора i и j
//i - итератор замены, j - итератор сравнения
//то есть *(a + i) вы будете заменять на *(a + j)
//алгоритм основывается на том чтобы *(a + j) было ближайшее справа число != 0
for (i = j = 0; i < n && j < n; i++, j++)
{
    //Сдвигаем итератор j вправо пока не дойдем до числа != 0
    //увеличивая k
    while (j < n && *(a + j) == c) {
        j++;
        k++;
    }
    //Если i != j то мы нашли как минимум один 0
    //производим замену
    if (j < n && i != j)
        *(a + i) = *(a + j);
}
```

Например возьмем те же числа, как в примере выше:

```
1 0 -4 3
```

Дойдя до `0` мы будем иметь `i = 1, j = 1, k = 0` после выполнения цикла получим `i = 1, j = 2, k = 1` и следующее что мы делаем это заменяем `*(a + 1)` на `*(a + 2)`, то есть `0` на `-4`. И теперь каждую итерацию мы будет заменять `i` элемент на `i + 1` (в нашем случае т.к. у нас один `0`).

В итоге получим:

```
1 -4 3 3
```

И т.к. `k = 1` обрежем последний элемент, получив:

```
1 -4 3
```

Comment: доходчиво, наглядно, коротко - спасибо большое